# How to unflag a comment when it was flagged by mistake?

Tags: support, comments, flags

I recently made an "oops" when I flagged a *valid* comment as off-topic, when I had meant to flag the **question** as an off-topic question that should be migrated. Unfortunately, unlike upvotes, downvotes, and other such features, there doesn't seem to be a way for the original flagger to remove an accidental flag.

Is there any mechanism to do this? Since human error is always a factor in any system, it seems like there should be a way for a flagger to undo such a mistake, especially in cases where the error is immediately recognized.

Comment: No, there's not. Enjoy your last 5 minutes of StackOverflow before you get ultra-banned for making such a mistake.

Comment: *... but on a serious note, I wouldn't worry. Mistakes happen.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relax.

Removal of a *valid comment as off-topic* would be a mistake of **[moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)**, not your - it's moderator who removes, not you.

It is reasonable to expect moderator to be capable of **[quick, competent and independent judgement of a situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119089/165773)** which naturally includes ability to find out when flag was submitted incorrectly.

Comment: About that moderator thing: Enough flags will automatically delete a comment, and in some cases 1 is enough.

Comment: @lunboks doesn't really change things, only shifts my target a bit - if a system is designed so that one flag submitted by mistake removes valid comment, it's the mistake of the system, not one of the user... And taking into account the context of off-topic flag that naturally involves _subjective judgement_, I'd say automatic removal like that would mean even more - severe mistake of system _designer_ - which is quite unlikely (softly speaking)

Comment: It seems true that "It is reasonable to expect moderator to be capable of quick, competent and independent judgement of a situation", but not 100% of the time.

It would be great there could be a mechanism to let them know if a mistake has been made.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're able to raise a second flag on the same comment, but if you can — and if you're so concerned — you can raise a custom flag asking that your "off-topic" one be ignored.

If you can't do that... well then you'll have to hope and pray with all your might that we won't delete the comment on sight.