# My flag has been declined, yet moderators did what I asked them to do. What gives?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131088/passing-different-number-of-arguments-to-a-params-method-at-runtime) was closed by vote as "not a real question", because the title has not been very descriptive. I improved the title, and put in a flag asking moderators to reopen the question. The question got reopened, but the flag came back "declined". I am still somewhat new to the flagging business, so I would like to find out what happened.

Comment: Perhaps the question was reopened by community votes, and the flag rendered unnecessary by the time a moderator arrived?

Comment: It's possible that the question also had incorrect flags against it, such as "Spam" or "Low Quality"; if a moderator has to decline one of them, they all get declined. I've had the [same thing happen to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157757/148949).

Comment: @meta.michael I thought this was a possibility, but then decided that moderators would certainly mark my flag helpful if the question got reopened even without their help. Isn't that what happens when, for example, moderators find a flagged question deleted by vote?

Comment: They don't even have to bother marking it manually, @dasblinkenlight; when a flagged post is closed, reopened, or deleted, the flags are automatically marked "helpful".

Comment: Oh, [you have skin in the game](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15131136/50776).

Comment: @casperOne Absolutely! In fact, all of my flags to reopen have been on questions that I answered.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Are you voting to reopen them because you *objectively* feel they are good questions, or because you have answers on them which you feel that may be deleted because the question would be deleted?

Comment: You have 122k on SO, why are you flagging at all? Vote to reopen. If the community doesn't agree deal with the fact. Then flag for moderator attention; if you really believe that the question was unjustly closed...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I was the first to vote to reopen. However, this question has had relatively low traffic before this post on meta, and it got an accepted answer, so I figured that flagging it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @das you should disclose that the accepted answer is *yours*.  That doesn't exactly make it a good question and as mentioned before, your objectivity on this matter is highly suspect as a result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I declined the flag.  Your change was to the title, and I still felt that the question was NARQ; there was no code sample showing what was trying to be done, etc.  Even as a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) guy, *I* had a little difficulty parsing it on first pass.

However, two community members came by and a mod (Will) reopened it after I rejected your flag.

Comment: The system works!

Comment: @JNK if by "works" you mean a crappy question with a not-too-clear problem statement and zero-effort stays open, then yes, it does.

Comment: I mean a group of users saw value in something and were able to resurrect it.  The system in question is the close/vote system. The alternative would have been to delete it (in which case nobody is better off).

Comment: @JNK Or it could have *stayed* closed, until the question was worked into shape.  People have to get over this idea that once a question is closed that it's unsalvageable.  The close notice is there to indicate that it *needs* to be salvaged.  If we delete it *then* we believe there's no hope for it.

Comment: @casperOne "crappy" is too subjective. This particular question is easy to misunderstand if you miss the "at runtime" portion of it. Once you see it, the question becomes 100% clear. In fact, even the last sentence is sufficient to understand what the author wants. Of the six people to attempt answering (including the deleted answers) four understood what's asked, and provided reasonable answers within minutes of each other. To me, this alone indicates that the question is not that crappy. Of course I am biased here, because I understood what is asked right away.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I obviously don't have the time to look into questions as much as you do.  Fact is, it should be cleaned up/made better.  Also, by your own admission, most of what you say can't be taken at face value because of the bias due to your being involved in the question (although I don't know what difference it makes whether it's open or closed to you, your answer is still there and you still have your rep).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Also, you can edit the title, but can't take the time to edit sentences such as "I have method with..." into something more comprehensible here?  What's the priority here?  If you are so adamant about the question being open, the least you could do is try to fix as much as you can about the question.  Right now, you've typed more on this meta post about the question than you have in actually *improving the question*.

Comment: @casperOne "but can't take the time to edit sentences such as ... 'I have method with...'" What's wrong with that sentence? The only problem that I can see is a missing article, but I don't see how adding it back would make that sentence "more comprehensible". Again, I'm biased here, because my native language has no articles; I nearly ignore them on reading. Anyway, it looks like you are almost trying to defend your decision, and you absolutely don't have to do so: I don't mind differences of opinion, and you have satisfied my curiosity by providing an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not trying to defend it.  I'm trying to point out that if you're going to vigorously pursue the reopening of a post, you should be doing it for the *right* reasons.  In this case, it doesn't appear that you did.

Comment: @casperOne I, on the other hand, would like to point out that there is no such thing as universally "*right* reasons". I mean, my reasons are perfectly "right" to me, and I don't see a problem if my definition of "right" does not match yours. In a community this large and diverse, differences of opinion are a given.

Comment: @das in general, yes, on SE though there are reasons that are more right than others.