# Has the policy changed on link-only answers?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I had a flag on a link-only answer declined several minutes ago:

> not an answer – dasblinkenlight 6 mins ago   declined - A link only answer is an answer - just a bad answer and **should be down-voted rather than flagged**. (emphasis added)

According to [multiple answers on what I think is the definitive question on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer), flagging was the right thing to do. Has this policy been changed?

Comment: Wrong flag type, I guess. It is a low quality answer, but it **is** an answer.

Comment: My understanding is the policy really hasn't been changed, but the moderators are being less forgiving when it comes to flags and the flag type.  Previously, flags where marked as helpful based on the apparent intent (was the user acting in good faith to try top keep the site clean).  But this year, mods started marking flags as helpful (or not) based on the accuracy of the specific flag.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers

Comment: @Oded I though that link-only answers were considered "not an answer" automatically. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Not sure that's how SO mods currently see it.

Comment: that "definitive question" you refer to is closed as a dupe, did you notice?

Comment: @gnat dot syntax chaining haha and dashblinkenlight, can you provide the data frames youre referring to? Ie. policy changed since when? Also, link-only are LOW-QUALITY because they go to the normal queues and normal users (not mods) deal with them. Unless you want a link-only answer to get converted to a comment ( while it does answer the question but link may die unexpectedely) you can use a custom flag and ask for it to get converted

Comment: @gnat I don't think that closing an older question as a duplicate of a much newer one was a good idea. However, the "can we have a consensus" question looks like an answer that I was looking for (i.e. that SO has no definitive policy on this, so moderators can decide each flag based on their own, somewhat arbitrary, judgement).

Comment: @mehow The time frame is "since the last time I checked" :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the NNA flag that was helpful was accepted by *mistake*. I know a big word *mistake* but according to the policy I am following like I said above - low-quality would have been more appropriate. See Oded first comment

Comment: @mehow "Although link-only answers are rather heavily discouraged, a flagger needs to take into account that currently, these carry a certain risk of flag decline... No matter what flag you use, there can always be a feasible explanation that it was wrong. Explanation will of course depend on the flag..." ([flagger's guide to link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154922/165773))